# How to make parts of an Appian label clickable?

Tags: appian

In my Appian interface, I have a [section layout](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.2/Section_Layout.html) and I want to have a part of the label, namely the `"End of Month"` be clickable:

```
{
  a!sectionLayout(
    label: "Report ""End of Month""",
    contents: { [...] }
  )
}
```

I thought of using a [link component](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.2/Link_Component.html), but the following does not work (it gives me a lengthy, unreadable label):

```
{
  a!sectionLayout(
    label: {
      concat("Report ",
             a!linkField(
               label: "",
               links: a!safeLink(
                 label: "End of Month",
                 uri: "http://the-full-url-pointing.to/end_of_month"
               )
             )
           },
    contents: { [...] }
  )
}
```

Is there a lengthy solution using a [Rich Text Component](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.2/Rich_Text_Component.html) inside the `label` of the section layout?

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature available to configure a link to any component's label.

And yes, you need to use Rich Text Component as following:

```
 {
  a!richTextDisplayField(
    value: {
      a!richTextItem(
        text: "Report ",
        style: "STRONG",
        size: "MEDIUM_PLUS"
      ),
      a!richTextItem(
        text: "End of Month",
        style: "STRONG",
        size: "MEDIUM_PLUS",
        link: a!safeLink(
          /*label: "End of Month",*/
          uri: "http://the-full-url-pointing.to/end_of_month"
        )
      )
    }
  ),
  a!sectionLayout(contents: {})
}
```

UI Screenshot:
[image]

Also, with rich text component, you can adjust the size, color and style of the text.

I hope, this helps.